# mysql stored procedure - how get the server name?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How can I get the current server name (or IP) in mysql into a variable (inside a stored procedure) ?

I want to put some conditions on my code depends of the server name/ip

Comment: Not sure if you're asking about the variable (`select @@hostname`) or the syntax.

Comment: There are several possible duplicate posts here.  Have you reviewed [this?](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+get+server+name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the current hostname and set into a variable -

```
SELECT variable_value INTO @local_hostname
FROM information_schema.global_variables
WHERE variable_name = 'hostname';
```